# jQuery creating radio buttons dynamically and attributes

Tags: jquery

I am using smarty and creating a dynamic html table that has radio buttons for each selection. When I  select a radio button, I would like a hidden row (with a comments text area) to show beneath the what I had just selected as that radio button.
When I run the following code, it will show a rows beneath every radio button, instead of the one i just selected:

**Smarty radio buttons:**

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input 
       type="radio" 
       name="refund_selected" 
       id="refund_selected" 
       value="{smartydynamictag}" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Hidden row of comments:**

```
<tr id="refund_comments" style="display: none;">
  <th colspan="6">Test Here</th>
</tr>
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$("input[name=refund_selected]").click(function() { 
    if ($("input[name=refund_selected]").attr('checked')) {
        $("tr#refund_comments").show(); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making an educated guess here as to how your markup is organized, but this *may* work:

```
$("input[name=refund_selected]").click(function() { 
        if ($("input[name=refund_selected]").attr('checked')) {
            $(this).parent().parent().next('#refund_comments').show(); 
        }
});
```

Also, do you have multiple of the same ID? Because the above code modification shouldn't even be necessary; you're not allowed to duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try refering THIS as you want to check only the radio you just checked

> ```
> $("input[name=refund_selected]").click(function() { 
>   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
>     $("tr#refund_comments").show(); 
>   }});
> });
> ```